# trigger other components method after success api call in angular9

Tags: angular, rxjs

After successful api call i needs to send the notification from ts file to trigger other product component method, instead of calling the method from template.please find the below code

componentone.ts

```
 export class CustomComponentOne extends Component2 implements OnDestroy {
    
      constructor(router: Router, renderer: Renderer2, elemRef: ElementRef, protected someLogoutService: LogoutService) {
        super(router, renderer, elemRef);
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        super.ngOnDestroy();
      }
    
      testMethod(): void {
        this.someLogoutService.performCustomLogout().subscribe((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            localStorage.clear()      
    }
        });
      }
    

    productcomponent

 export class changeProductComponent extends productcomponent implements OnInit {
    
      protected authService: AuthenticationService;
      constructor(authService: AuthenticationService, userService: UserService) {
        super(authService, userService);
        this.authService = AuthenticationService;
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        super.ngOnInit();
      }
    
    
    
        methodToCall(): string {
       
          return this.customLoginAdapter.getCustomLoginUrl();
        
      }

producntcomponent.htm

 <p ngIf="methodToCall()">testprod</p>
```

instead of calling  methodTocall from template,is there any other way to call from componentone.ts file. i have tried with @output event emitter its did not help because product component is in parent directive (it contains lot of child directive) we can't customize that one. can we achieve it in any other way like using subject. kindly help me out this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use behaviorsubject for that

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example-l2b3dw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[behaviorsubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)

Answer (score 1):

I am using a service whenever I have two components that need to communicate with each other and Input/Output is not feasible.

Create a service that has a public property of type subject.

- Inside the subscribe of performMDCIMLogout in CustomComponentOne call
  service.subjectProperty.next(value).
- Inside changeProductComponent subscribe to service.subjectProperty
  and call the methodToCall

Docs: [https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Example(provided by Tony): [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example-l2b3dw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: can you give me a piece of code .then it should be help ful

Comment: Tony provided the stackblitz you need. Please mind to upvote both answers :)

Comment: The difference between behaviourSubject and Subject is that the behaviourSubject has a initial value.